# Dropout is not working correctly in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please find the code at below, actually here i am facing problem while showing dropout menu..

```
import React from "react";
import Nav from "../../../components/navigation";
import Dropout from "../../../components/dropout";
import CategoryGrid from "../../../components/grid";
import classnames from "classnames";
import style from "./style.scss";

var data = [
  {
    categorytitle: "Shoes",
    category: [
      {
        Category1: "Boots"
      },
      {
        Category2: "Sneakers"
      },
      {
        Category3: "Flats"
      },
      {
        Category4: "Booties"
      },
      {
        Category5: "Mules"
      },
      {
        Category6: "Heels/Pumps"
      },
      {
        Category7: "Clogs"
      },
      {
        Category8: "Slippers"
      },
      {
        Category9: "Sandals"
      },
      {
        Category10: "Sale"
      },
      {
        Category11: "Shop All"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    categorytitle: "Activities",
    category: [
      {
        Category1: "Comfort Shop"
      },
      {
        Category2: "Run Shop"
      },
      {
        Category3: "Trend Guide"
      },
      {
        Category4: "Athletic"
      },
      {
        Category5: "Casual"
      },
      {
        Category6: "Dress"
      },
      {
        Category7: "Outdoor"
      },
      {
        Category8: "Walking"
      },
      {
        Category9: "Foot Health & Wellness"
      },
      {
        Category10: "Narrow Shoes"
      },
      {
        Category11: "Wide Shoes"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    categorytitle: "Clothing & More",
    category: [
      {
        Category1: "Handbags/Purses"
      },
      {
        Category2: "Active & Yoga"
      },
      {
        Category3: "Coats & Jackets"
      },
      {
        Category4: "Athletic"
      },
      {
        Category5: "Dresses"
      },
      {
        Category6: "Tops"
      },
      {
        Category7: "Sweaters"
      },
      {
        Category8: "Socks"
      },
      {
        Category9: "Sunglasses"
      },
      {
        Category10: "Rain Gear"
      },
      {
        Category11: "Wide Shoes"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    categorytitle: "Top Brands",
    category: [
      {
        Category1: "Sam Edelman"
      },
      {
        Category2: "Clarks"
      },
      {
        Category3: "Dr Martens"
      },
      {
        Category4: "Lucky Brand"
      },
      {
        Category5: "New Balance"
      },
      {
        Category6: "Skechers"
      },
      {
        Category7: "Sperry Top-Sider"
      },
      {
        Category8: "Sorel"
      },
      {
        Category9: "TOMS"
      },
      {
        Category10: "UGG"
      },
      {
        Category11: "Vionic"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    targetUrl: "/",
    imagePath:
      "/images/image_1.png",
    title: "WORK SHOP"
  }
];

let CategoryMenuDropout = false;
class Navigation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      currentHoverIndex: -1
    };

    this.titleHover = this.titleHover.bind(this);
    this.openCategoryMenuDropout = this.openCategoryMenuDropout.bind(this);
    this.closeCategoryMenuDropout = this.closeCategoryMenuDropout.bind(this);
  }

  titleHover(currentHoverIndex) {
    this.setState({
      showCategoryMenuDropout: true
    });
  }

  openCategoryMenuDropout() {
    this.setState({
      showCategoryMenuDropout: true
    });
  }

  closeCategoryMenuDropout() {
    this.setState({
      showCategoryMenuDropout: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav
          data={this.props.data.map(({ title }, a) => ({
            title,
            target: ""
          }))}
          onHover={this.titleHover}
        />
        <Dropout
          open={this.state.showCategoryMenuDropout}
          onMouseOut={this.closeCategoryMenuDropout}
          onMouseEnter={this.openCategoryMenuDropout}>
          <div
            className={classnames(style.cartegory_wrapper)}
            onMouseOut={this.closeCategoryMenuDropout}
            onMouseEnter={this.openCategoryMenuDropout}>
            <CategoryGrid>
              {data.map((ele, index) => (
                <div
                  className={classnames(style.cartegory_menu)}
                  key={"Key-" + index}>
                  <h3 className={classnames(style.cartegory_menu_title)}>
                    {ele.categorytitle}
                  </h3>
                  <ul>
                    {Array.isArray(ele.category) &&
                      ele.category.map((d, i) => (
                        <li key={"Key-" + i}>{d[`Category${i + 1}`]}</li>
                      ))}
                    {ele.imagePath && <img src={ele.imagePath} />}
                  </ul>
                </div>
              ))}
            </CategoryGrid>
          </div>
        </Dropout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Navigation;
```

This above code is what i trying to implement dropout menu with different-different categories.

Here when i am trying to click dropout menu items but dropout itself hiding, please help me out on this.
Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: can you please create a demo at stackblitz.com

Comment: Yes, without demo it would be difficult to analyze/fix

Comment: not getting how to give demo

Comment: this is anything related to onMouseOut & onMouseEnter?